# Importing libraries in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Noob question incoming. I'm using node on my project and i'm importing some libraries by using `import *** from ***`. However [this library](https://github.com/dshongphuc/magic-mouse-js) says that to import it I only need to add the `css` and `js` files to my `index.html`, and then do

```
options = {
"cursorOuter": "circle-basic",
"hoverEffect": "circle-move",
"hoverItemMove": false,
"defaultCursor": false,
"outerWidth": 30,
"outerHeight": 30
}
magicMouse(options);
```

But it doesn't let me do that, `magicMouse is undefined`, but then if I do import the `js` file into my `index.js` it doesn't let me write the options. `options is not defined`

So, basically, how can I import that library?

Comment: I'm not sure about your library but not having a `let`, `const` or `var` before options looks very weird. I would suggest adding that.

Comment: You would need to share more about your file structure and the exact way in which you are linking to the files. This particular library is odd in that it's not a node module that you'll access via `import`.

Comment: in the demo page the guy seems to be using it in vue.js, and has the `options` inside `data`, any way i can emulate that in vanilla js?